# Is there any situation when text should be center aligned (horizontally) in an input?

Tags: forms, gui-design, input-fields, text, alignment

I recently tried to use some animations in my design and I checked some nice examples as inspiration, like this: "[Inspiration for Text Input Effects](https://tympanus.net/Development/TextInputEffects/)". Some of them had the text centered.

[image]

[image]

I know it is just an example to illustrate the animation, but I was wondering if it is any case when it is a good idea to center the text in a field and not to let the user write from left to right (on mobile, if the value is limited to a small number of characters or anything else). What do you think?

Comment: @Alvaro My question is not related to the labels, is about the alignment of the text inserted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only reason I can think of to modify the paradigm of entering text on an input from left to right (in a LTR language) is **when it helps to visualize the output**.

For example it might be helpful when entering text for the subtitles of a film, because these are commonly centered, and the user can see the output as the text is entered.

Answer (score 0):

When you have something like a five digit pincode that for aestethical purpose consists out of five actual inputs (for spacing and border for example), it's quite okay to use centered text inside the input.

The problem is with the way the human eye scans a form.
In a vertical form the eye shoots to the start of every new line. Inputs with centered text are therefor harder to scan. In a serious form this could harm conversion.

So yes, I think you can use centered text in inputs and forms, but only on those rare occassions where it suits the design.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your answer correctly, but a pin code is basically an input type password and even you insert it with a mask or in four different fields, why insert it from the center?

Comment: I'm thinking about an image in this question http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/70516979?noredirect=1

Comment: Exactly, the text is inserted from left, see the implementation (the top voted answer).